# dataset visualizer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I've had problems with the dataset visualizer that comes with 2005 and 2008 blowing up on me. I can't recall the error at the moment, but I would think that because it is intermittent that it is data dependent. Then again, the visualizer should be capable of displaying whatever can be put into a ds, or at least not blow up.

Does anyone know of a good alternative ds visualizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in checking out [Mole](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-for-visual-studio/).

I haven't used it extensively, but I do like it from what little I've used it. It seems like a very powerful visualizer. I also hear that it's gaining traction over at Microsoft for their internal development.

Answer (score 6):

Try the [Righthand Dataset Debugger Visualizer](http://blog.rthand.com/page/Righthand-Dataset-Debugger-Visualizer.aspx)

Comment: It works good. I especially like how it allows you to view original values, deleted rows, etc.

Comment: Just a note that the main page has moved to http://blog.rthand.com/page/Righthand-Dataset-Debugger-Visualizer.aspx